# Can ArgoCD deploys using info published via API

Tags: argocd, argo-workflows, argo, argocd-notification

Does ArgoCD deploys based on info handover from an API call? So far I tried declarative approach for deployments (updating master branch and pull based deployments), never tried via an API call.

Comment: I think you are asking "how to not use git with ArgoCD", is that it? If so, what's the point of ArgoCD in the 1st place. ArgoCD is GitOps and pull based.

Answer (score 0):

Argo CD has a robust API. Basically anything you can do via the UI or CLI you can do via the API. For example, you can create Applications and trigger syncs.

Comment: Appreciate the reply here. But my question is more on the lines like: Basically team will release the output of a Python scripts in an api call that needs to be deployed on an EKS Cluster. I need to setup ArgoCD to deliver the deployment based on the info I get from those api’s

Comment: I think the question needs more details. I'm not sure what it means to "release the output of a Python scripts".

Comment: Sure, let me elaborate here:

I setup my ARGO for a pull based (with every master branch merge) in a declarative way.
Is there a way to setup to do the deployment using an API Call? My team wants to generate API'S (python based) based on their services and want to see if Argo can deploy the changes based on their API's.
Basically the info is delivered via API Call in my teams case.
Not sure if its feasible or possible with current releases.